# MAMP html source folder

Tags: html, mamp

Hi i'm a newbie to Apple products, I installed MAMP on my Mac and now have no idea where the default folder where all the html files are put go to. Also new to web development. Anyone help?

Comment: Applications ▹ MAMP ▹ htdocs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the MAMP application, click on "Preferences..." then go on the "Apache" tab. 
There you will be able to locate the default folder. You can create a new one and set it as default there too.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used MAMP in a while, but [according to their FAQ](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/faq.html#q12) it looks for the HTML files (by default) in: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

This seems like an odd place to store them. You can (and probably want to) change the default in MAMP's preferences to a different folder so you can store your files somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in the htdocs folder, but when you go to look at it with your web browser - htdocs will appear at http://localhost:8888/.

So if you create an index.html file, that will be what gets loaded when you visit http://localhost:8888/